# unable to retain a value pushed in a globally declared array in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, global-variables

i have declared an array in a constructor and im trying to push a value in the function declared.but when i try to access that in another function there is no scope. PFB my code

```
function a() {
console.log("Constructor");
this.methods = ["getStatus","getLocation"];
}
a.prototype.invoke(){
this.methods.push("functionName");
console.log("this.methods new 123------------->",JSON.stringify(this.methods))
}

a.prototype.methods(){
 console.log("JSON.stringify(this.methods) ---------------------->",JSON.stringify(this.methods))
}
```

below is the output that is getting printed

```
this.methods new 123 ---------------------->    ["getStatus","getLocation","functionName"] 
JSON.stringify(this.methods) ----------------------> ["getStatus","getLocation"]
```

There is no scope in function methods
I want the array as below

```
JSON.stringify(this.methods) ----------------------> ["getStatus","getLocation","functionName"]
```

I'm stuck kindly help

Comment: How do you call these functions?

Comment: @GergoErdosi : i call the invoke function first which in turn calls the methods function internally

Comment: This code doesn't even run, the function `methods()` has a collision with the property name `methods`. If I change the name of the function, then it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/yqyb9296/